# Setup launchd task to run when USB device is connected

Tags: macos, usb, launchd

I'm hoping to setup a script to run automatically when a USB device is connected, however I'm not certain how to trigger it.

Unfortunately the USB device isn't a volume, so I can't use the `onmount` trigger for it, and while I have a script command to interact with it, it doesn't include an API to trigger actions automatically; i.e- I can verify that it's connected, but I'd have to poll continuously until it is. I don't expect to be able to get the developers to add such functionality any time soon either (if at all).

So, is there a generic way that I can configure a `launchd` task that will trigger when a USB device is detected, and thus avoid the need to poll for it? If this isn't possible then are there any other alternatives capable of triggering a shell script when I connect the device?

Comment: Did you already check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240117/execute-an-application-on-mac-os-x-when-a-particular-type-of-usb-device-is-conne) SO question?

Comment: Didn't come up in my search, so thanks for the link! Sounds like `launchd` won't do for shell scripting (since a shell script can't call the necessary API once it launches), but I may have found a workaround that will create a file in a known location, so I can instead watch for that; not pretty, but it'll do! Not sure what to do about this issue though, as the duplicate is on a different site?

Comment: I think the question is fine here.

Comment: @Haravikk you can call the necessary API by using this amazing utility that will call xpc_set_event_stream_handler to remove the event from the queue, and then call your desired application. Allowed me to come up with a solution using shell scripting. Check out github.com/snosrap/xpc_set_event_stream_handler